# LaTeX wants a $ where there shouldn't be one

Tags: symbols, errors

I have a variable name that I need to include mid-paragraph.  The variable is called "oral_read_score".  LaTeX seems to think that I meant the "r" and "s" to be subscripts, and gives an error unless I change to `$oral_read_score$`, which is not what I want.  Is there some option I can use to turn this error off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

oral\_read\_score

\verb!oral_read_score!

\end{document}
```

[image]

LaTeX reserves the special character `_` for math mode subscripts; you can escape this character using `\_` for its use in text mode; the second option uses `\verb` to write the expression verbatim.

Comment: Many solutions in TeX/SX come without explanation. Explaining why yours is the right solution may help save millions of future LaTeX users precious time.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I added some remarks.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underscore}
\begin{document}
oral_read_score
\end{document}
```